# Do aws opswork support CoreOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am trying to launch a instance from a coreos ami in opswork and its failing on setup itself.I'm not able to login into the machine it's asking for password.Do opswork supports coreos?

Answer (score 2):

According to the AWS Opsworks online documentation only the following Linux AMIs are supported:

- Amazon Linux (see the AWS OpsWorks console for the currently supported versions)
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7

You can also use custom AMIs based on these operating systems.

Sources:

AWS OpsWorks Operating Systems
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-os.html

AWS OpsWorks Operating Systems --> Linux Operating Systems
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-os-linux.html